# different results by SMO, NaiveBayes, and BayesNet classifiers in weka

Tags: classification, weka, svm, smo, liblinear

I am trying different classifiers of Weka on my data set. I have small dataset and I am classifying my data into five classes.
My problem is that when I apply cross validation or percentage split classification by different classifiers, I get very different results.

For example, when I use `NaiveBayse` or `BayseNet` classifiers, I have an F-score of around 40 for all classes, but using `SMO` I get an F-score of 20. The worse result is obtained when I use `LibLinear` classifier which gives me a F-scores of around 15.

Maybe I should mention that since `LibLinear` classifier doesn't accept nominals, I assign a code to each of the possible nominal values and use them as `Numeric` values in my dataset.

Can anybody tell me why I get such different results? I expected all classifiers to have roughly similar results.

In addition, when I use `LibLinear` on my test set, I have all data classified under one of the classes and there is no instances in the other four classes.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect similar results? For small data set especially I think different methods could easily lead to different predictions. Also linear model has tolerance threshold that would cause early termination before convergence. It's something you can play with in LibLINEAR or SMO for instance.